# SQL Select statement in PHP missing entires from table 1 and 2 because table 3 lacks the product_id

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, so I have a fully working select query, but I need to add a new function in, and this requires me to select previously unnecessary entries.

The current Select Query

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM products, products_description, specials 
WHERE products_tax_class_id >= '0' 
  AND products.products_id = products_description.products_id 
  AND products_description.products_id = specials.products_id 
  AND products.products_id = specials.products_id
```

but this doesn't retrieve anything that doesn't have an entry in the specials table, and I now need it to do this, I have tried several suggestions found on the internet but I cant get it too work, please help

Comment: use proper ANSI joins. Then you can use left join, which will enable you to select rows which both do and don't have an entry in the new table.

Comment: For further help, please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` instead. An `INNER JOIN` will join two tables where the condition match, and only rows that intersect on that condition. A `LEFT JOIN` will join two tables together on a condition, but the results in the right-table can be empty (meaning that the product must exist, but the special is not required).

Also the usage of aliases makes your code easier to read. Since it appears there are duplicate column-names here, I'd advise you to be explicit about your select-list. Doing `SELECT *` is not necessarily a good approach.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN products_description AS pd
    ON p.products_id = pd.products_id 
LEFT JOIN specials AS s 
    ON p.products_id = s.products_id
WHERE products_tax_class_id >= 0
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly, and thanks for simplifying the table names too :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use join query as

```
SELECT products.*, products_description.products_id as product_description_id, specials.products_id FROM products
JOIN products_description ON products_description.products_id = products.products_id  
LEFT JOIN specials ON specials.products_id = products.products_id WHERE products.products_tax_class_id >= '0'
```